# Autosave issue in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, netzke

In the given code,

```
class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_one :criteria, foreign_key: "crt_sup_id", :autosave => true   
  self.primary_key = 'sup_id'  
end  

class Criteria < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :supplier, foreign_key: "crt_sup_id"  
  self.primary_key = 'crt_id'  
  self.table_name = 'criterias'  
end
```

autosave is not working when I am submitting the form. Supplier records are created but not Criteria.

### Form code

```
    class SupplierForm < Netzke::Basepack::Form
      def configure(c)
        c.model = 'Supplier'
        super
        c.items = [
          {field_label: "Name", name: :bname},
          {field_label: "Detail", name: :detail},
          {
            layout: :hbox, border: false, defaults: {border: false}, items: [
            {
              flex: 1,
              layout: :anchor,
              defaults: {anchor: "-8"},
              items: [
                {field_label: "Value 1", name: :criteria__val_one, xtype: :checkbox, nested_attribute: true},
                {field_label: "Value 2", name: :criteria__val_two, xtype: :checkbox, nested_attribute: true}
                ]
            }
            ]
          }
        ]
      end
    end
```

### Controller code

```
def index
end
```

Comment: where's the code for the form and the controller that processes it?

Comment: I am using netzke, the form and controller works fine. In the supplier model when I am using **raise self.inspect** I am getting all the values but not saving

Comment: obviously they're not working fine, but okay.

Comment: How we can parse the form params in model and save it

Comment: If I am using **after_create :create_criteria** a new row is created in the criteria table. But I want to save the values from the form.

Comment: Please show the code for the form and the controller that processes it.

Comment: I have added the code to the question. pls do check

Comment: Solved with the help of Netzke author. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with the help of Netzke author. Replace criteria__val_one with criteria_val_one and
criteria__val_two with criteria_val_two. Create virtual attributes in the model class. Now all the values entered in the form is accessible with these virtual attributes and can be saved. Credit goes to **Max Gorin**. Thanks for the great work (Netzke)